# Why is my ng-class ignoring the animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, animation

I am trying to use ng-class to set the color of an icon dependent on certain conditions however I also have a class wrapping the div in which it's in that causes it to fade in.

For some reason the animation is being ignored and the icon colored is simply displayed.

```
    <div class="change-container" >
        <i data-ng-class="{color: 'green'}"></i>
    </div>

.change-container {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    -moz-animation: change-widget-fade-in 0.7s ease-in 1;
    -o-animation: change-widget-fade-in 0.7s ease-in 1;
    -webkit-animation: change-widget-fade-in 0.7s ease-in 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the syntax of `ng-class` . A style can not be added directly by using `ng-class`. The correct syntax for `ng-class` is

```
<ANY
  ng-class="expression">
...
</ANY>
```

> Expression to eval. The result of the evaluation can be a string
>   representing space delimited class names, an array, or a map of class
>   names to boolean values. In the case of a map, the names of the
>   properties whose values are truthy will be added as css classes to the
>   element.

**[Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)**

In your case, you first need to define a class in css, like

```
.green-color {
  color: 'green'
}
```

and then you can add this class using

```
<div class="change-container" >
    <i data-ng-class="{'green-color': true}"></i>
</div>
```

You can use a Boolean expression in place of `true` to conditionally add the `green-color` class.